# Removing extra view created when using a custom view

Tags: android

Using the following code:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, this);
    }
}
```

The layout is simple:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f00"/>
```

The `hierarchyviewer` shows the following:

[image]

The `CustomView` hierarchy is useless and I would like to remove it.

Is there a way to create a custom view extending a `ViewGroup` without adding that additional `View`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CustomView is already a RelativeLayout in you XML layout you can just delete the RelativeLayout with "@+id/custom_view_id" and use as father the  tag
That will merge the children with the CustomView without using an extra RelativeLayout.
The CustomView will setBackgroundColor

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f00"));
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, this);
    }}
```

and the layout xml file will be:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <!-- children here -->
</merge>
```

Comment: Yes, `merge` definitely is the way to go. Thanks!